# How should disconnected devices be handled after a session has been started?

Tags: ios, google-cast, chromecast

My application is crashing after disconnecting the power from my Chromecast after a session has been started.  As I expected the `GCKApplicationSessionDelegate.applicationSessionDidEndWithError` method is called.  After exiting the method my application crashes due to `[GCKWebSocket forceCloseWithError:] at GCKWebSocket.m:215:`.

I'm able to reproduce this in the **cast-ios-demo-player** app by disconnecting the power to the device and by pressing the End Session button.

Comment: See if it still happens w/ the 1.0.5 iOS SDK.  developers.google.com/cast/downloads

Comment: It's still broken in the 1.0.5 iOS SDK.  I've been told it's fixed in the 1.0.6 SDK which hasn't been released as of now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The crashing issue has been fixed in SDK 1.0.7.